# Querying Dates in MongoDB returning empty df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mongodb

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection in Python, using:

```py
pd.DataFrame((tuple(mongo.db[collection_name].find({'Dates':{
                                                             '$gte': datetime(2020, 1, 1), 
                                                             '$lt': datetime(2020, 1, 2)
                                                            }
}))))
```

In my collection, the `'Dates'` attribute is of type `Date` and looks like this: `2020-01-15T00:00:00.000+00:00`

When I run the command I get an empty pd, which I feel is because of the time added on by Mongo to the date object

is there a way to store the date without a time, or efficiently append time onto the datetime object in python

Comment: `datetime` creates a **python** Date object, however you need a **BSON** Date object. I am not familiar with python but it could be [bson.timestamp.Timestamp](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/timestamp.html#bson.timestamp.Timestamp)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, thanks, but it was simply my datatime() object - see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using:

`datetime(2020, 1, 1)`

Use:

`datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)`